# Look for a cleaner way to perform this searching function

Tags: ios, objective-c, algorithm, cocoa-touch

Given that there are 2 classes A and B.

They both get an integer attribute , ID.

Now you have an `arrayA` which contains all classes A object and an `arrayB` which contains all classes B object.

What is the best or cleaner way to select the objects in `arrayB` which has the same id as the object in `arrayA`?

(Someone suggests intersection. I think this complies faster but the code looks not nice)

Here is the sample code:

```
NSMutableArray *resultArray = [NSMutableArray array];

for (ClassB *bObject in arrayB) {  
    for (ClassA *aObject in arrayA) {  
        if ([bObject ID] == [aObject ID]) {  
            [resultArray addObject:bObject];  
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest approach is to (a) build an array of ID values; and then (b) use that a predicate:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ID IN %@", [arrayA valueForKey:@"ID"]];
NSArray *results = [arrayB filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

See the [Predicate Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/AdditionalChapters/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001789).

Comment: Thanks for you answer, this is what i look for.

Comment: I didn't accept any answers because i tried those answers and they do not work.
For this one, I think both answers are great and it makes me hard to pick the best.

Comment: No worries. (I was afraid you were just a new user unfamiliar with the "accept" process.) BTW, I won't take offense if you want to accept IVlad's answer instead. He tackled "how to do it in computationally efficient manner" whereas I focused on "how to do it most easily". Personally, I'd advise against premature optimization (i.e. don't write custom search algorithms unless you have to), but if you hit some point where the above becomes computationally infeasible, then definitely pursue further optimization.

Answer (score 2):

Your current solution has complexity `O(nm)`, where `n` and `m` are the lengths of `A` and `B` respectively.

You could sort the array `A` by ID in `O(n log n)` and then, for each element of `B`, [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) that ID in `A`. This will be `O(n log n + m log n)`. `n log n` because of the sort and `m log n`, because for each of the `m` elements of `B`, you do one binary search on `A`, which runs in logarithmic time.

You could also add each element in `A` (only its ID actually) to a [hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) (might be called a map or a dictionary in your language of choice. I'm not familiar with objective-c.) and then, for each element of `B`, look up its ID in the hash table you built. This will be `O(n + m)`, but it can degenerate to a worse complexity in some cases. In practice though, this will probably be the fastest.

Comment: Thanks for your detail explaination.